# On a Spring Boot application I can't send http requests to the server from javascript fetch

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-boot

I am running a spring server on localhost:8080 and I use a PageController that returns a login page with thymeleaf which uses javascript fetch to perform a post with entered values.

```
// select the submit button element from the DOM
const submitBtn = document.getElementById("submit-btn");
console.log(1);
// add an event listener to the button for the "submit" event
submitBtn.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
    // prevent the default form submission behavior
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(2);

    // define the data to be sent in the request body
    const userData = {
        username: document.getElementById("username").value,
        email: document.getElementById("emailf").value,
        schoolNumber: document.getElementById("school-n").value,
        dob: new Date(document.getElementById("dob").value).toISOString().split('T')[0]
    };
    console.log(JSON.stringify(userData) + " 3");

    // send the POST request
    fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/v1', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(userData)
    })
        .then(response => {
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
            }
            // handle successful response
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('There was a problem with the fetch operation:', error);
        });
});
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Welcome to The Community</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form-m">
    <label for="username"></label><input type="text" id="username" value="tell me thy username">
    <label for="emailf"></label><input type="email" id="emailf" value="yourmail@example.org">
    <label for="school-n"></label><input type="number" id="school-n" value="000">
    <label for="dob"></label><input type="date" id="dob" value="yyyy-mm-dd">
    <button type="submit" id="submit-btn">submit</button>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/main.js}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
@Controller //PageController.java
public class PageController {
    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String loadLogin(Model m) {
        m.addAttribute("name","sex");
        return "login";
    }

}
```

```
  @PostMapping //default mapping for api/v1, UserController.java
    public void saveNewUser(@RequestBody UserSM u) {
        userService.saveNewUser(u);
   }
```

You will see control points inside the code and they don't pass the first checkpoint ( I believe they do pass but because of the site refresh they disappear)

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: I don't get any errors inside the console

Comment: I'd guess that submitBtn.onsubmit is not happening because buttons don't have submit events (forms do) - did you try adding the submit handler to the form element?